# Google Sheets- group 4 columns from every group together to create a payroll list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to group 4 columns for each group to create a payroll checklist from my planning sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fcfUDCA1q5MVS12NGCOO15ZJTxDad-dlrR51hlsDkqc/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be really appreciated!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDslQ.png)

1. tried filter flatten but it wont extend to 4 columns. (=FLATTEN(C5:H28;K5:P28;S5:X28;AA5:AF28;AI5:AN28)
2. Filtered non empty cells from employee name

Answer (score -1):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,choosecols(vstack(A4:G7,I4:O7,Q4:W7),7,5,1,6),
     filter(Σ,choosecols(Σ,2)<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, exactly what i was looking for, first time i use that kind of formula :let(Σ;choosecols(vstack)  where should i find information for learning advanced formula like theses !!!   many thanks! works great!

Comment: [these tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLv9Pf9aNgemvXxLZfObnb3cvcG6gerfOB) on new functions (map,lambda,byrow,bycol,scan,reduce...) should be helpful